# How is a 15 bytes instruction transferred form memory to CPU?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, instruction-set

Assuming we are using a x86-64 machine, it means it's general registers are 64 bits long, its data bus can handle 64 bits at a time, its ALU can handle at max 64 bit number (right?).

Having a simple instruction like

```
MOV $5, %eax
```

moves a 32 bit number through the 64 bit data bus into the CPU register.

I have read the following:

```
An x86-64 instruction may be at most 15 bytes in length.
```

My question is, how is this possible if a data bus is at max 64 bits? how can it handle an instruction with 120 bits. Does the CPU fetch it at multiple cycles?

My second question is, are there special registers with bigger length to store all that 120 bits?

Comment: Regular instructions only handle up to 64 bits at a time, but the SIMD extensions of newer processors can handle 256 or even 512 in one instruction.

Comment: data bus and instruction length isn't relevant. The 8088 has an 8-bit data bus to save cost, but its instructions can be longer. But x86 CPUs already have 64-bit data bus since at least the Pentium 4 era, with multi-channel memory give multiple times that number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Instruction Encoding

A modern X86 instruction is built from the following:

- Prefixes (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
- VEX (0, 2, 3)
- OPCODE (1)
- ModR/M (1)
- SIB (0,1)
- DISP (0, 1, 2, 4)
- IMM (0, 1, 2, 4)

#### A prefix is zero to four bytes:

Group 1: LOCK or REP
Group 2: Segments (CS, SS, DS, ES, FS, GS—not all available in 64 bits) and branch hints (i.e. is a branch more likely to be taken or not?)
Group 3: Operand size (66H, is mandatory for some instructions!)
Group 4: Address size

#### VEX

VEX is for the AVX extension (mostly)

#### OPCODE

OPCODE is the actual instruction, *only 8 bits* if you do not count the *VEX* and some other prefixes/*special bytes* such as the famous `0F`. (On 8086 & 80186 processes the code `0F` represented `POP CS` which later was repurposed for extended OPCODEs.)

#### ModR/M defines the mode

It tells us which register and/or memory mode is used along this instructions. Some instructions do not support all the available modes.

#### Scale, Index, Base

SIB is an extension to the ModR/M.

#### Displacment

DISP is the displacement, an immediate added to an address register (as in [ESP+13]) It can also be the direct address to a memory location.

#### Immediate

IMM an immediate value (in `MOV EBX, $8` — the 8 is the value loaded in `EBX`, the immediate value.)

Note that IMM is generally limited to 32 bits. The `REX` can be used to get 64 bits, but it's not available with all instructions (because the total number of bytes for any one instruction is 15 bytes). To load 64 bits in a register, you always load it from memory. One way of doing so is to use an IP based address. (Something like this: `MOV R8, [RIP, -42]`) Also I've noticed that in the past compilers such as gcc did not use that instruction. With 64 bit processors, though, a 32 bit displacement is available so the value can be pretty much anywhere (±2Gb).

### Loading of Instructions

The 64 bit processors load instructions in the instruction cache. It loads 16 bytes at a time (it may vary depending on the processor). The processor then interprets those bytes. Depending on the processor, it may convert those bytes to a set of RISC instructions or just execute the instructions *directly*.

For example, the `LOOP label` instructions is really the near equivalent of at least two instructions:

```
SUB ECX, 1
JNZ label
```

Some processors had a hard time with such in the past so a LOOP was very slow. One reason is that a `SUB` changes many of the `EFLAGS` when `LOOP` changes none.

The interpreter does not load instructions in a register. It loads it in the CPU and handles it in the corresponding Unit (ALU, ACU, FPU, etc.) There is the RIP register that points to the current instruction, though. As far as you're concerned, the RIP is always pointing either at the start of the current instruction or the start of the next instruction.

How it really is implemented, I do not know. They probably very quickly (instantaneously) determine which unit is concerned and push the instruction there. The size is not that complicated to determine so they can quickly get all the bytes and push them on the concerned unit FIFO, probably as a 15 or 16 bytes value (i.e. one item in the FIFO is most certainly always 16 bytes, one byte may be ignored, which manes the hardware does not even have lines to read it!) Those bytes would be positioned at the same location each time. So if the input does not have a `LOCK` or `REP`, it would put say `00h` in that FIFO byte.

Note that moving 16 bytes in a FIFO between units is nothing. GPUs have been moving much larger amounts of data for years in their FIFOs.

You could say that these FIFOs are additional registers. The register file is the same thing as a FIFO, only it has random access instead of "PUSH/POP" type of a mechanism. Both use similar technologies, a.k.a. memory, to keep data in a FIFO and in a register.

### Documentation

I would suggest the first document, currently titled:

> [Intel® 64 and IA-32 architectures software developer’s manual combined volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, and 4](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)

From Intel as a good read about the available instructions (not absolutely everything, but more than enough to get started!)

Comment: There aren't any x86-64 CPUs that don't decode to uops.  The last x86 CPU not to do that was P5 Pentium, dual issue superscalar pipeline that can pair simple x86 instructions, but complex instructions couldn't be split up to pair better.  Transmeta internally software JITing to a VLIW ISA is also noteworthy, but means that x86 "code fetch" is purely data processing for it.

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting about first-gen Xeon Phi; Knight's Corner is based on P5 with a not-quite-AVX512 vector ISA added.  So yes, there have been x86-64 CPUs that don't decode to uops. :P

Comment: `sub ecx,1` / `jnz` has never been slower than `loop` on any CPU except for code-size reasons on early CPUs (like 8086 and maybe up to 386).  LOOP is slower on all x86-64 CPUs, except Bulldozer/Zen where they're both 1 uop.  [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35742570)/

Comment: Also, I think you incorrectly capitalized LOOP in there somewhere, when you meant to talk about looping with sub/jnz instead of the LOOP instruction.  Anyway, `dec`/`jnz` was a problem on P4 because `dec` doesn't modify all the flags, leaving CF unchanged, but ADD/SUB which write all flags have never been a problem on any CPU. [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](//stackoverflow.com/a/36510865)

Comment: x86-64 uses RIP, not EIP.  And *The size is not that complicated to determine so they can quickly get all the bytes and push them on the concerned unit FIFO,* Not even close.  x86 instruction-length decoding is *hard*, and a major problem for high-performance x86 CPUs that want to decode 4 or 5 instructions per clock.  There's a whole separate pipeline stage for it in Intel CPUs, with a buffer between predecode and decode.  `add cx, 1234` will stall that stage with a Length-Changing Prefix stall.  But anyway, decode happens in one place, before uops are routed to execution units.

Comment: You missed a couple things: REX; 64-bit immediates; 64-bit displacements.

Comment: *because the DISP is rather small so the value needs to be really close by* What are you talking about?  RIP-relative addressing uses a `rel32`.  Almost all code is built with a code-model that places all static code and data with 2GiB of each other, so all static is always addressable with RIP-relative addressing.  `int global_foo;  int f(){return global_foo;}` will use a RIP-relative `mov` load, when compiled by any sane compiler including GCC.  But gcc will use `mov r64, imm64` any time it needs a wide constant, it's not great but it's usually better than static data.

Comment: No, REX can be used with all instructions to indicate 64-bit *operand-size*.  e.g. `add r/m64, imm32` needs a REX prefix.  REX only changes the size of immediates for `mov`, from 5 byte `mov r32, imm32` (with no ModRM) to 10 byte `mov r64, imm64`  (REX + same opcode + 8 bytes).  Your update didn't really help at all, and made it wrong in different ways.  \@prl was pointing out 3 different omissions, not 2.

Comment: *With 64 bit processors, though, a 32 bit displacement is available* makes little sense.  RIP-relative addressing is new with x86-64.  If you're talking about 32-bit compilers, they didn't use it because it wasn't available.

Comment: The `0Fh` opcode prefix code was never used for co-processors. On original 8086 it was supposedly a `pop cs`, which was later (286+) repurposed as an opcode extension.

Comment: @ecm Indeed! Actually the co-processors used `ESC` instead. I fixed my comment. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

Instruction fetch is a separate datapath from data load/store.  It's not done *using* 64-bit `mov` instructions.  There is dedicated logic that handles fetching and decoding variable-length unaligned x86 instructions.

A single instruction can span a 4k page boundary so its bytes are from 2 discontiguous physical pages!  The front-end has to be able to fetch instruction bytes and concatenate them in a buffer.

Even 8086 had a small instruction prefetch buffer, although that wasn't necessarily needed for decoding because on 8088 it was smaller than the longest instruction (not including prefixes.)

---

**See [David Kanter's Sandybridge writeup](https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/3/) for a diagram of the front-end in Sandybridge** (and Nehalem and Bulldozer).  Also [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/).   See https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen#Decode for more about the front-end in recent AMD.

On P6 and SnB-family Intel CPUs, code fetch and predecode (to find insn boundaries) happens in 16-byte blocks, finding lengths for up to 6 instructions per cycle and consuming up to 16 bytes of x86 machine code per cycle.  If an instruction runs past the end of a block, the predecoder keeps those bytes around until the next cycle.  Agner Fog's microarch pdf has some details about optimizing to avoid pre-decode bottlenecks; x86 decoding is *hard*.  e.g. an operand-size prefix changes the length of the *rest* of the instruction in some cases.  e.g. a `66` prefix is the only difference between `add eax, imm32` (5 bytes) and `add ax, imm16` (`66` + 3 bytes).  The predecoders in Intel CPUs stall in this case, taking extra cycles to handle it.  (Alexis' answer claims that length-finding is easy.  It is most certainly *not* easy with all the ISA extensions that have accumulated over the years, where a VEX prefix is an invalid encoding of another instruction for example.  And it gets that much harder when you're trying to do multiple instructions in parallel, because you have to consider multiple starting points for all instructions after the first one.  Older CPUs used to be slow to decode prefixes, e.g. taking an extra cycle per prefix or even escape byte.  But modern mainstream Intel (not low-power) can handle any number of prefixes with no penalty.)

Instructions are fed to the decoders up to 4 at a time (or 5 or 6 with macro-fusion).  Depending on the uarch, this can produce up to 7 micro-ops (uops) (4-1-1-1 pattern on Core2/Nehalem), 4 (SnB-family before Skylake), or 5 (Skylake).  SKL still only has 4 decoders, but allows them to produce up to 5 uops, e.g. for patterns like 2-1-1-1.

[image]

Decoding x86 instructions in parallel is such a bottleneck that modern CPUs (Intel since SnB-family, AMD since Zen) cache decoded uops to shortcut that for hot portions of code.  Pentium 4's trace cache was an early experiment in that direction which worked out poorly (and it didn't have the decoder throughput to maintain acceptable performance on trace cache misses).

See also [What's the relationship between early 90s Pentium microprocessor and today's Intel designs?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/whats-the-relationship-between-early-90s-pentium-microprocessor-and-todays-int/4370#4370) on retrocomputing, where my answer talks some about why P4 was a CPU-architecture dead end, and how P6-family (PPro / PIII) evolved into Intel's current Sandybridge-family.

---

**All x86-64 CPUs are new enough to be high performance with wide internal data paths, but 16 and 32-bit CPUs have the same 15-byte max length (including redundant prefixes)**.  They would probably use a buffer at least big enough to hold an instructions not including prefixes, if they decode those separately before looking at the opcode, modrm + extra addressing mode bytes, and/or immediate.

Except for original 8086, where a 64k code segment full of REP prefixes for one instruction *is* valid.  At that point Intel hadn't defined any limitations on instruction length, and 8086 decoded prefixes separately from the rest of the instruction.

---

Also related:

- [With variable length instructions how does the computer know the length of the instruction being fetched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269368/with-variable-length-instructions-how-does-the-computer-know-the-length-of-the-i)
- [Instruction decoding when instructions are length-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204086/instruction-decoding-when-instructions-are-length-variable)